# put a border around header and paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a single border around the header and paragraph.  Currently I have two separate border around the header and the paragraph. How can I put a single border around them?

```
<style type="text/css">
h1{
 font-family: consolas;
border: 2px solid #73AD21;
border-radius: 25px;

}
p{
font-family: Consolas;
border: 2px solid #73AD21;
border-radius: 25px;

}
</style>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>
```

Comment: Put them into a container and give the container the border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Harry suggested above, simply add them inside a wrapper and set your styling on the wrapper instead. Like so:

```css
div {
  font-family: consolas;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you cannot or don't want to change your markup, you could simply remove the bottom left and right `border` and `border-radius` for your `h1` element, and also remove the top left and right `border` and `border-radius` for your `p` element. This will also yield the appearance you're looking for.

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: consolas;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

p {
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>World</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Chris.  Could I ask one more question?  I am trying to put an image on the left side and header and paragraph on the right side? How can I create two columns so the image is on the left side and the texts are on the right side?

Comment: No problem! Sure thing! Though you should first mark this question as solved (if it is) and then post a new question since this one is about borders. Once your question is posted share the link here.

Comment: I did!  Here's the link Chris :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816500/how-can-i-put-image-file-on-the-left-side-and-texts-on-the-right-side

Answer (score 2):

```css
h1{
 font-family: consolas;
}
p{
font-family: Consolas;
}
.wrapper{
 border: 2px solid #73AD21;
border-radius: 25px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>
</div>
```

Take the both tags under a wrapper and give the expected border. Please have look on the following:
***CSS:***

```
<style type="text/css">
h1{
 font-family: consolas;
}
p{
font-family: Consolas;
}
.wrapper{
border: 2px solid #73AD21;
border-radius: 25px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
</style>
```

***HTML:***

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or - if you *can't* put a wrapper arround it, do it like this:

```
h1 {
  font-family: consolas;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  font-family: Consolas;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-top: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJOwLY