# How can I put image file on the left side and texts on the right side

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to put an image on the left side and texts on the right side.
How can I do this? Also if the image is too big, how can I resize it?

```css
.container {
  background: #34618c;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: consolas;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
p {
  font-family: Consolas;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img src="c:\users\user\Desktop\test.png" align="left">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

I get an image on the left side but I only want the border around the text not around the image as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
img {
  width : 20%;
}

.container{
background: #34618c;
border-radius: 25px;
width : 80%;
float : right;
}
h1{
 font-family: consolas;
border: 2px solid #73AD21;
border-radius: 25px;

}
p{
font-family: Consolas;
border: 2px solid #73AD21;
border-radius: 25px;

}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<div class="container">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>
</div>
```

Like this?

Comment: hi Earl, yes kind of but the border is around the image and the texts.  How can I just have the border around texts?

Comment: Or you can try to use position absolute. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are **many, many ways**  you can achieve this. Too many to list all of them. I do however suggest using a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) since this will help you in getting good and consistent results across your pages.

One of Bootstraps' many features is the [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), which aids in laying out your design.

> Grid systems are used for creating page layouts through a series of rows and columns that house your content.

Basically, Bootstrap provides certain classes which lets you define "rows" and "columns" to your layout. Each row, should have a total *column width* equal to 12. This means that you can have only one column with a column-width of 12; 2 columns each with a column width of 6; 3 columns with 4 width and so on.

For your particular case, it looks like you want 2 columns for your row. One to put your image in and one for your container. Here's that layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">  <-- column with "6" width
      //image goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">  <-- column with "6" width
      //container goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What each `<div>` does here is quite obvious from the class-names they have. Each `col-md-6` is one of our 2 columns. The `6` means that it has 6/12 width (half the width). The `md` is a *breakpoint* for medium devices. Basically, if the device you're viewing this page on is classed as "medium sized" or larger, it will have 6 column-width - otherwise 12. You can see what this actually means by shrinking the window of your browser ([demo](http://recordit.co/UxFfMdDHHa)). If you want the content to break sooner, replace `md` with `lg` (large); if you want the break to happen at even smaller devices use `sm` (small) or `xs` (extra-small).

The full code for your app can be found on [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sLxu03a7/) or in the demo below:

```css
.my_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.my_container div {
  background: #34618c;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.my_container h1,
.my_container p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: consolas;
}
.my_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%, 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="my_image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x200')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="my_container">
        <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <p>World</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, do check the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com) and don't forget to include the library to your project. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Chris, <div class="my_image" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x200')"> how can I use my image from local here?  <div class="my_image" img source="local path"> doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you just replace the url. Change from `<div class="my_image" style="background-image: url('placehold.it/300x200')">` to `<div class="my_image" style="background-image: url('your_local_path_here')">`

Comment: what did you put as the url?

Comment: c:\users\name\desktop\name.img

Comment: and where do you store your project/html files?

Comment: @Ninja, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, yes I did.  Used table for the image.  Thanks for your help Chris!